# Soundness idea of basic zero knowledge prood

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am having a hard time figuring out the soundness proof of the bellow zero knowledge protocol.  As it is a typical proof, I would love to deeply understand it.

---

#### zero knowledge argument that $h \in <g>$

Lets $G = (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.  The prover wants to show to the verifier that $h \in <g>$.  The common inputs are $G, h, g$ and the prover has the value $a$ such that $h = g^{a}$.

The protocol goes like...

```
         Prover                         Verifier
--------------------------------------------------
y = g'^k mod n           y
                 --------------->  choose challenge c
                         c
                 <---------------
s = k + c*r mod |G|
                         s
                 --------------->  check if g^s mod n = y*h^c mod n
```

In the case the protocol was poorly explained her, here is another version of it [Non-interactive proof that an element is in a subgroup](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/non-interactive-proof-that-an-element-is-in-a-subgroup)

---

Many thanks!

didier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this zero knowledge proof;

- it isn't explained very well
- it gives the verifier more information than it claims to

Lets go through them in order:

> It isn't explained very well

The problem is that the terminology it uses in the proof statement differs from the terminology they use in the protocol description; for example, the protocol uses this value 'r' without explaining what that value is.  Here's the protocol redone to use the same terminology:

```
         Prover                         Verifier
--------------------------------------------------
Prover selects random value k
y = g^k mod n            y
                 ---------------> 
                                   Verifier chooses challenge bit c
                         c
                 <---------------
s = k + c*a mod n-1
                         s
                 --------------->  check if g^s mod n = y*h^c mod n
```

The idea is that, if the protocol is run honestly and if $h = g^a$, then the check will always verify, because $g^s = g^{k + ca} = g^k \cdot g^{ac} = y \cdot h^c$.  The further idea is that someone could try to create a valid looking transcript by selecting s and c first, and then computing $y = g^s (h^c)^{-1}$, with the hope that these randomly selected values would be indistinguishable from a valid set.

> It gives the verifier more information than it claims to

It claims to just show that $h \in <g>$, or in other words, there exists an $a$ such that $h = g^a$.  However, the verifier can deduce more than that; not only can he deduce that such an $a$ exists; but in addition that the prover knows that value.  In fact, this Zero Knowledge Proof is actually a proof-of-knowledge of the value of $a$, not just its existence.

You can show that we cannot really create the 'Zero Knowledge Proof' of a nontrival binary statement (one which is either true or false, but nontrivial in the sense that it cannot be deduced directly).  The reason is that the existence of such a ZKP protocol would allow someone to deduce the statement directly (without a prover being involved).  Consider if we had such a ZPF protocol, then someone could just assume that binary statement, and run the proof/verification mechanism honestly with themselves; if the proof verifies, then they have learned that the statement must be true.

Comment: Are you saying that a ZKPoK is inherently weaker because it leaks the fact that the prover knows the witness?  Formally speaking, ZKPoK is stronger than plain ZKP.

Comment: @DavidCash: no, I am saying that there are statements for which no ZKPoK exists, and one such statement is $\exists x: g^x = h$ (at least, we don't think so; if either the DLP and factorization problem is easier than we think, the above statement may be trivial).   There does exist a ZKPoK proof that "I know such a value $x$", however that's not the statement that was originally claimed.

Comment: @poncho You are talking about plain ZK in your last paragraph right? The verifier is computationally bounded (PPT). What about a verifier just given a graph and without the prover needs to deduce if it is for instance 3-colorable? How should the verifier run a meaningful proof/verification mechanism without having access to the prover who knows the witness and learn if the statement is true?

Comment: You should replace $n-1$ in your calculation of $s$ by the order of the subgroup. $g$ does not necessarily generate the full multiplicative subgroup. And y should be chosen smaller than the order of the subgroup.

Comment: concerning the difference between pure ZK proofs and proofs of knowledge, this is a proof of knowledge. Right now I can't think of a ZK proof of being in the according subgroup without knowing the element, but it might be possible.

Comment: @tylo: yeah, I did replace |G| with n-1, and I ought to have at least noted why.  The protocol was written as a MODP group; it wasn't specified that n was prime; however since it assumes the prover knows |G|, that means that the factorization of n is known.

Comment: Usually this proof is done with n being prime, then your protocol would be fine, with n-1 being a multiple of the group order. But if n is not prime,  your check at the end fails: $y\cdot h^c $ mod $n = g^{k+ca \text{ mod } \phi(n)} \neq g^s$.

Answer (score 0):

Soundness does not necessarily hold.

If `2 < m` and `n = (m*m)-1` and `h = (m*m)-2` and `g = m`, then `h` is not in the subgroup generated by `g` but `y=1` and `s=0` will cause any even challenge to result in acceptance.

What is the challenge space?

Comment: Zero knowledge proofs do not insist that a challenge be accepted only if the proposition being proved is true; in fact, they require that someone be able to generate a valid-looking transcript even if the proposition was false.

Comment: However, zero knowledge proofs by default _do_ insist that the verifier has at most a $\hspace{1.14 in}$ negligible probability of accepting a false statement. $\;$

Comment: Most ZKP's I've seen allow a 0.5 probability per round of accepting a false statement; that is consistent with your "any even challenge to result in acceptance".